# unexpected EOF cronjob error

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I have the following cronjob:

```
2 15 * * * mysqldump -u user -ppass dbname | gzip -9  -c > /var/www/backup/dump-$(date +%Y-%m-%d).sql.gz
```

but it produces following error:

`/bin/sh: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching ')'

/bin/sh: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

I tried ommiting `-c` but no luck. I have one more line in my crontab but I don't think it's related:

```
0 0 * * * find /var/www/backup/* -mtime +15 -exec rm {} \;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `%` character should be escaped in `cron`.

So,

```
2 15 * * * mysqldump -u user -ppass dbname | gzip -9  -c > /var/www/backup/dump-$(date +\%Y-\%m-\%d).sql.gz
```

Comment: Will it work also using single quote? As in `$(date +'%Y-%m-%d')`