# Unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"' - MySql backup script

Tags: bash, shell

The Script:

```
mysqldump -u user -p pass database > /home/user/public_html/site/DB_bak/database_$(date +"%Y%m%d").sql
```

I'm guessing it has to do with the date portion and the `%` sign.

I have basic shell scripting knowledge.

Also my password has a `@` in it, could that be part of the problem?

Comment: Enclose your password in single quotes `'password'`.

Comment: Is the date portion (`database_$(date +"%Y%m%d")`) fine or will that cause an error?

Comment: The date portion is good.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error: `/usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell: -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching "'` then it says `/usr/local/cpanel/bin/jailshell: -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file`... Why is there 2 lines?

Comment: In [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14853638/698699) answer [sputnick](http://stackoverflow.com/users/465183/sputnick) says that the `%` character must be escaped for cron jobs. I'm going to try that.

Comment: That was it... problem solved after escaping all the `%` signs in the command: `\%`.

Comment: Pleased don't edit "SOLVED" into your title. A solved question is indicated by select an answer -- or, in this case, by the question being closed as a duplicate (which should happen soon; there are already 3 close votes).

Comment: @KeithThompson Umm, I didn't edit the title.

Comment: @John: I see; somebody else edited "(SOLVED)" into the title. (I removed it.)

Comment: @anubhava: I see you added "(SOLVED") to the title of this question. That's not a good idea. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/116101/167210

Comment: OP commented that problem got solved so I added that in the title indicating same.